# Comparison in for loop

Tags: java, sql, arrays, comparison

I am fairly new to java and came across a problem while working on a project where i need to extract some data by comparing each result that i get out of a for loop with the other.

The forloop is to get results out of an sql query & the code for the forloop is as following:

```
      for (Map<String, Object> row : results) {
            String data= row.get("getdata").toString();
            }
```

The data recieved out of this when the loop runs 2 times is somewhat like:

`a12:1:123;b23:2:234;c24:3:344`

`a12:1:123;b23:2:234;c24:4:345`

when, in the above data for the same first vale, the second value after `":"` is different, I  want to get the third value, for example between `c24:3:344` & `c24:4:345` the second value is different i.e. `3` and `4` so I need to get `344` and `345`.
similarly I need to find any such data in the results received by the for loop.

All you help is greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because you are asking us about a bug without showing us code.  Without concrete code, we can only guess what the problem might be, which is not useful to you or future readers.  If you can [edit] your question to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem, this downvote may be retracted.

Answer (score 0):

Break it down a bit.

You have a loop, you're iterating over a structure and you need to compare every row with the previous row. Each iteration you will get the current row and compare it to the previous row, then set the previous row to the current row for the next iteration.

```
prevRowData = null;
for(Map<String, Object> row : results) {
    String currRowData = row.get("getdata").toString();
    if(prevRowData != null) {
        compareRows(currRowData, prevRowData);
    }
    prevRowData = currRowData;
}

private void compareRows(String currRowData, String prevRowData) {
    // split the row data into an array on the colon/semi-colon delimiter 
    // to make it easier to compare each portion
    String[] currRow = currRowData.split(":|;");
    String[] prevRow = prevRowData.split(":|;");

    // if the first part is equal and the second part is not equal
    if(currRow[0].equals(prevRow[0] && !currRow[1].equals(prevRow[1])) {
        // print out the third part of each row (or return it or whatever)
        System.out.printf("currRow: %s, prevRow: %s", currRow[2], prevRow[2]);
    }
}
```

This is pretty rough and you should do some validation and tailor it to your needs but I hope I have illustrated the basic idea.

Comment: can you please explain what is prevRow and currRow in this and where do we store the value of prevRowData? I am sorry if this is a stupid question

Comment: As the loop iterates over the structure `currRow` is the current row, the row that we have pulled out of the map in this iteration. `prevRow` is the row that we pulled out of the map in the previous iteration. We store the previous row so that we can compare it with the current row.